# Rank by Agent and Month

Tags: sql, grouping, partitioning, ranking

I have a table with similar data to the following:

```
Agent | TCV | Parent AccountID | AccountID | Month
------+-----+------------------+-----------+--------
John  | 100 | ABC12345         | Sept13445 | 2
John  | 200 | ABC12345         | Sept345   | 2 
John  | 150 | CDE12345         | Sept546   | 2
John  | 200 | FTE1456          | Oct3467   | 2
John  | 100 | ABC12345         | Sept13445 | 3
John  | 200 | ABC12345         | Sept345   | 3 
John  | 150 | CDE12345         | Sept546   | 3
John  | 200 | FTE1456          | Oct3467   | 3
```

What I need is a way to show a grouped ranking by agent, then parent accounrDID each month for each agent. The idea being that in the export, there'd be a column for agent, TCV, parentaccountDID, and month.

So if all agents had 10 parentaccountDIDs (but potentially multiple accountDIDs under each), it would rank them by the grouped TCV of the parentAccountDID. So there'd be 10 lines of data for John's 10 parentaccountDIDs based off of grouped TCV in month 2, then 10 lines of data for the 10 parentaccountDIDs based off of grouped TCV in month 3, etc. etc.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT agent, tcv, parent_accnt_id, accnt_id, curr_month
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY curr_month, parent_accnt_id ORDER BY curr_month) rnk 
 FROM your_table
/
```

With your data this is what you get:

```
AGENT    TCV    PARENT_ACCNT_ID    ACCNT_ID    CURR_MONTH    RNK
------------------------------------------------------------------
John     100    ABC12345           Sept13445     2            1
John     200    ABC12345           Sept345       2            2
John     150    CDE12345           Sept546       2            1
John     200    FTE1456            Oct3467       2            1
John     100    ABC12345           Sept13445     3            1
John     200    ABC12345           Sept345       3            2
John     150    CDE12345           Sept546       3            1
John     200    FTE1456            Oct3467       3            1
```

Comment: Would this be performance wise good on high volume databases...???
i think this will tend to be slower with rising numbers

Comment: @Vineet Verma - This was not the question and Oracle claims that analytic functions are faster. This is Oracle example as OP does not specify the RDBMS. And your example will not work, sorry. It simply gives rank=count of rows, which is from 1 to 8. You may revise your example and test it.

Comment: :- the output will be if the sort will be placed properly as in Order by 4 asc. this way he will be able to get the response ordered as given by question. also i can agree that the analytic functions might be better, but i have seen scenarios where these functions create issues rather than solution. anyways i have also suggested him to look for Dense Rank over function that might help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have Oracle SQL Database
Try the below query it might help you as needed:

```
select Agent ,TCV ,ParentAccountID,Month,count(1) from table group by  Agent ,TCV ,ParentAccountID,Month
order by 5 desc
```

Also you could check(google) "Dense Rank Over" function something as below:

```
select Agent ,TCV ,ParentAccountID,Month,dense rank over(Agent ,TCV ,ParentAccountID,Month) from table group by  Agent ,TCV ,ParentAccountID,Month
```

it ranks the values and the sorts the result.